# Typescript - How to make sure array of possible values has only one value of certain type

Tags: typescript, enums, unique, uniqueidentifier

So I have an enum like this:

```
enum StringsVals {
  'aaa',
  'bbb',
  'ccc'
}
```

and I define a variable x which can be an array of enum values like so:

```
const x: (keyof typeof StringsVals)[] = ['aaa', 'bbb']
```

Is there a way I can make sure that x only contains those values and they are unique in order to avoid this for example?

```
const x: (keyof typeof StringsVals)[] = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'aaa']
```

Or there is so much that Typescript can do?

```
enum StringsVals {
  'aaa',
  'bbb',
  'ccc'
}
const x: (keyof typeof StringsVals)[] = ['aaa', 'bbb']
```

Comment: Have you considered using HashSet to have uniqueness property and use enum values to avoid typos?

`var mySet: Set<StringsVals> = new Set<StringsVals>();

mySet.add(StringsVals.aaa);
mySet.add(StringsVals.aaa);
mySet.add(StringsVals.bbb);

mySet.forEach(item => console.log(item));`

Comment: Are you trying to create a type that expresses that there must be no duplicates or are you trying to ensure that there are no duplicates at runtime?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, the first one: type that expresses that there must be no duplicates